# How can I reset Google play store pin if I can't remember it?

Tags: google-play-store

I want to download apps that my parental controls won't let me do and I can't remember my pin. How can I change it please or reset it?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way out is to reset your Google account by;

## Change or reset your password

You can change your password for security reasons or reset it if you forget it. Your **Google Account** password is used to access many Google products, like Play-store, Gmail and YouTube.

## Change your password

> - Sign in to My Account.
> - Under "Sign-in & security," select Signing in to Google.
> - Choose Password. If you see a prompt to sign in again, sign in.
> - Enter your new password, then select Change Password.

## Reset your password

> *Go to the Account support page.
>   *Follow the instructions. You'll be asked some questions to confirm it's your account and an email will be sent to you. If you don’t get an email:
>
> - Check your Spam or Bulk Mail folders
> - Add noreply@google.com to your address book.
> - Request another email.
> - Check all email addresses you might've used to sign up or sign in to your account.
>
> *Choose a password that you haven't already used with this account. Learn how to create a strong password.

Source: [Google Account Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/41078?hl=en)

Comment: I'm stuck because I can't remember my pin for downloading apps.